# Redundancy of structures

Tags: c++

I'd like to get some opinion from more experienced programmers. I have a structure like:

```
struct Position {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

but I need to store for example longitude in a structure like:

```
struct Longitude {
    int from;
    int to;
};
```

both of them are actually the same with different names, but `x` and `y` are misleading in the case of `Longitude`. Would you use some `typedef Position Longitude` instead of defining `Longitude` structure (but then we have x/y there...)? Or create the same redundant structure with another names? Or maybe there are other alternatives?

Comment: `Longitude.from` and `Longitude.to` look even more misleading than `Longitude.x` and `Longitude.y` to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd be inclined to keep them separate.

In `C++` a `struct` and a `class` are identical constructs (excepting the default access of member variables and functions).

As your application evolves, you'll probably want to add more functions and member data to the `struct`s. At that point the two definitions will start to diverge. Keeping them separate from the outset will assist this development.

If you're concerned about code duplication then you can always inherit from a base `class` or `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if it is feasible, I would store it internally as either `x/y` *or* `from/to` and provide a public accessible interface for conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I would make Position class parent of Longitude and user getters and setters instead bare attributes:

```
class Position {
public:
    int getX() { return x; }
    int getY() { return x; }
    void setX(int x) { this->x = x; }
    void setY(int y) { this->y = y; } 
protected:
    int x;
    int y;
};

class  Longitude : public Position  {
public:
    int getFrom() { return getX(); }
    int getTo() { return getY(); }
    void setFrom(int from) { setX(from); }
    void setTo(int y) { setY(to); } 
}
```

Comment: Your class Position is pointless. Either provide real members functions with non trivial semantic or set the attributes as public because in the current situation they are exposed. Moreover, inheritance and entity classes do not mix well. This is not Java =)

Comment: @Yuushi You are right, too much time working with java. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Davidbrcz If he wanted to keep two different names for the same variables it would be quite redundant to have two pairs of attributes, one at the parent and another and the child class. On the other hand, he could keep public attributes for the parent class and have getters and setterts in the child class but on my opinion that would make this class tree a litle bit hazy.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
struct Position {
    int x;
    int y;
};

using Longitude = Position;
```

c++11 provides such sugar sintax, you have the same data with other name (you still have the same x/y stuff, but I dont really see the trouble of using them.)